# External gradle plugin 'com.bmuschko.tomcat' not found

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I want to add the tomcat plugin to my gradle build, but the plugin cannot be found , gradle shows the error

```
Plugin with id 'com.bmuschko.tomcat' not found.
```

I followed the steps on the github page of this plugin, but it does not work.
In my project I have general build.gradle in this I am loading my project.gradle in this I defined the tomcat-plugin configuration.

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
ext {
 debug = false
}

apply from: 'project.gradle'
group = myGroup
version = myVersion + '-SNAPSHOT'
```

***project.gradle***

```
//https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat"


apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "project-report"
apply plugin: "war"
```

I can ensure that dependencies can be resolved from my machine, because other gradle projects work, so that it should not be a network issue, there is no proxy configuration etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `buildscript{}` into your main `build.gradle`. The `buildscript` process is outside the regular Gradle build. Same applies to `plugins{}` as well (since they are equivalent.)

So if you put

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.2'
    }
}
```

into your `build.gradle`, it would work.

[Update]

I have created a [sample gradle project](https://github.com/chenrui333/so-48133903) with the [fix](https://github.com/chenrui333/so-48133903/commit/5fd1ec2ba0c0e11e111ccc9098878b4eff66f33d) in it.

And the TravisCI build is [here](https://travis-ci.org/chenrui333/so-48133903/builds/326189181).

Comment: @AlPhaba, I have build a fresh repo and TravisCI build, let me know if that works for your issue.

Comment: Big thanks, i could build your sample project. I took your project as template and now its working with my projekt as well. I guess my tests of your orignal post was to messy.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may try using the plugin type:

```
apply plugin: com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.TomcatPlugin
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat"
```

in your project.gradle file.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it does not work either, just the error message changes so that the com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.TomcatPlugin was not found

Comment: @AI Phaba, exactly. It doesn't work for me too.